# Методы объекта, инкапсуляция

Tags: java

Всем привет :)

Столкнулся с вопросом, наверно глупым.
Есть у меня класс **User**, делаю я его так, что бы он сам мог сохранятся и удалятся и т.п. в БД. То есть, реализую в нем паблик методы `User.save()` и `User.delete()` etc., которые просто пердают себя в **DAO**. `new JDBCUserDAO().insert(this);`

Но задумался, что идет просто проброска и лишний код, а не лучше ли иметь почти пустой класс **User** и просто кидать его по другим объектам, которые его и будут сохранять или обрабатывать. Допустим имея некий объект класса **User**, для его сохранения передать его в **DAO** `new JDBCUserDAO().insert(user);`

Я предполагаю, что можно и так и так. Но текущей вариант(первый), вроде бы как, соответствует понятию инкапсуляция, но создается лишний код.

```
public class User {

            private String name;
            private String mail;


        public User(String name)  {
            DAO<User> userBD=new JDBCUserDAO();
            User user=userBD.takeByName(name); 
            this.name = name;
            this.mail = user.getMail;
        }


        public User(String name, String mail){
            if (!isNameOK(name)) {throw new WrongArgsExeption("Name filed="+name);} else {this.name = name;}
            if (!isMailOK(mail)) {throw new WrongArgsExeption("Mail filed="+mail);} else {this.mail = mail;}
        }

        public void save() throws WrongArgsExeption {
            DAO<User> userBD=new JDBCUserDAO();
            if (this.isInBd()) {throw new WrongArgsExeption("This Name or Mail already used.");}
            userBD.insert(this);
        }

        public void update()  {
            DAO<User> userBD=new JDBCUserDAO();
            userBD.update(this);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getMail() {
            return mail;
        }

}
```

Простите за кашу в голове, я только учусь :)

Comment: А dao - это ваш класс?

Comment: Мне кажется, у вас имеет место большая ошибка. Вы каждый раз создаете новый экземпляр базы данных, нигде ссылку на нее не сохраняя. Это бессмысленно. Предлагаю следующее:  
 засунуть методы добавления и удаления пользователя в класс базы данных. Типа: database.remove(user) и database.add(user)

Comment: dao мой класс, метод дао класса создает Statement и ResultSet, а соединение берет из другого класса, которые выдает его из пула

Comment: так создайте в нем ArrayList User'ов и методы для добавления User'ов из него

Comment: Или я чего-то не понимаю. Он со статическими переменными оперирует, что-ли? Singleton?

Comment: дата-класс не должен заниматься своим сохранением, этим должен заниматься класс работы с бд (то есть второй вариант)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Инкапсуляция* и *сокрытие данных* — близкие понятия, но не идентичные.

Инкапсуляция означает, что ваш класс нельзя *сломать*, перевести в несогласованное состояние. Скажем, если вы пишете класс `Data`, и позволяете программисту устанавливать значения полей `Day` и `Month`, он может установить несуществующую дату 30 февраля.

Чтобы избежать таких ситуаций, классы позволяют изменять значения связанных полей только вместе. Скажем, в `Data` можно завести метод `setData(int year, int month, int day)`. Если вы передаёте на вход неправильную дату, метод выбрасывает исключение и не меняет состояние объекта на неправильное.

Это и есть инкапсуляция.

Ваше решение никак не соответствует *инкапсуляции*. Возможно, оно соответствует *сокрытию*? Иногда под сокрытием понимают такую ситуацию, что про класс вообще ничего не известно.

Но это не совсем правильно. Представим себе класс `Line` который представляет математическую линию.

Линию можно создать, используя общее уравнение прямой *Ax + By + C = 0*, либо, например, координатами двух точек, через которые она проходит.

```
public Line(double a, double b, double c) { ... }

public Line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) { ... }
```

Предположим, мы хотим узнать пересекается ли наша прямая и окружность `Circle`? Код пересечение кажется не принадлежит классу `Line` и классу `Circle`, он касается их обоих.

Третий класс, какой-нибудь сервис пересечений, мог бы заниматься решением этой задачи. Для решения ему [нужны](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/circle_line_intersection) коэффициенты *A*, *B* и *C* общего уравнения.

Класс `Line` должен их предоставить. Но как? Если мы откроем доступ к этим коэффициентам, их можно будет несогласованно менять. Вместо предоставления прямого доступа, мы закрываем доступ методами-геттерами `getA()`, `getB()` и `getC()`.

Точно также для решения других задач мы предоставляем геттеры для *x1*, *y1*, *x2*, *y2*. Значит ли это, что `Line` хранит все возможные способы представления прямой? Возможно. Или возможно, он вычисляет их на лету. Тогда какие параметры хранятся там на самом деле?

Мы не знаем, и не должны. Для решения наших задач нам эта информация не нужна. Это *сокрытие*. В каком то смысле ваше решение способствует именно сокрытию реализации.

Но здесь есть один подводный камень, и он большой. Класс `User` отражает сущность предметной области. Это *пользователь*, наверное, у него есть *имя* и, возможно, какие то *права доступа*.

А вот то, что относится к хранению пользователя — лишняя информация для предметной области. Ваш класс знает о базе данных, и о том, как он хранится. Потом вам потребуется кэшировать записи, и придётся добавлять кэш туда же. Потом для отображения пользователя на сайте, нужно будет конвертировать его в JSON.

Если идти по этому пути, классы быстро обрастут ненужной функциональностью. Они станут огромными и их трудно будет поддерживать. *Всемогущие классы* иногда называют антипаттернами *Божественный объект*. Божественный, потому что может всё.

Следуя принципу *Единственной ответственности* (*Single Responcibility Principle*), мы отделяем предметную логику от логики хранения и логики представления. Тогда у нас получается простой класс `User`, плюс простой класс `UserRepository` — который сохраняет и загружает пользователей в базу и из базы, плюс простой класс `JsonSerializer`.

**Что хорошего в вашем решении**

Не смотря на нарушение принципа единственной ответственности, иногда программисты делают так, как сделали вы. Ваше решение это паттерн *Активный объект* (*Active Object*), то есть такой объект, который что-то делает в предметной области, а ещё умеет себя сохранять и загружать.

Если предметная логика у вас небольшая, если в объектах почти нет методов, а только данные, решение, основанное на *Активных объектах* и в самом деле проще и быстрее.

Поэтому, прежде чем всё переписывать, оцените, будет ли значимая отдача. Небольшие *активные объекты* — приемлемое решение, надо просто оценить требования.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, наставили меня на путь) Мой проект для обучения, так что пойду все переписывать и штудировать новые материалы